# C# parse syntax line into components

Tags: c#, parsing, syntax, wpf-controls

I'm trying to parse a syntax line, something like:

CopyFolder [-Source]  [-Target]  -Overwrite -Recursive -ContinueOnError

and dynamically add WPF components/controls to a StackPanel to prompt the user for input such as

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="-Source" />
    <TextBox Uid="-Source" />
    <TextBlock Text="-Target"/>
    <TextBox Uid="-Target"/>
    <CheckBox Uid="-Overwrite" Content="Overwrite"/>
    <CheckBox Uid="-Recursive" Context="Recursive"/>
    <TextBlock Text="-ContinueOnError"/>
    <ComboBox Uid="-ContinueOnError">
        <ComboBoxItem>True</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>False</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I'm attempting to use the following function to get the various pieces of the syntax line:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string[] ParseArgs(this string source)
    {
        return Regex.Matches(source.Trim(), @"[\""].+?[\""]|[\'].+?[\']|[\<].+?[\>]|[\[].+?[\]]|[\{].+?[\}]|[^ ]+")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Note that because -ContinueOnError has  after, it gets a ComboBox for input where -Recursive is a ckeckbox...  ContinueOnError can be null, true, or false (specify if not null), where -Recursive can only be true or false (include the switch or exclude the switch).  There is another ComboBox possibility, and that is a set of values following the switch such as:

Service -Name  -Action {Install, Uninstall, Start, Stop}

Where I am having issues is when a switch is not followed by a value (-Overwrite, or -Recursive in the first example).

NOTE: XAML was typed and untested, not copied and pasted, please excuse typos, etc.

Comment: Is your issue with the Regex you are using? That is to say, can you specify a bit where the problem actually lies?

Comment: The RegEx seems to parse the arguments correctly...  I got tired of trying to figure it out and created an XML for each item (there were 68) and used that instead fortunately my manager liked the XML solution better as it allowed for more flexibility in the future.

Comment: Ok good that you found a solution. I noticed the regex split this `-Arg {opt1 opt2}` in two, which might make it hard to parse correctly. You could have tried `string.Split('-')` and go from there, but surely an XML configuration sounds way more solid and robust for this relatively complex and flexible setup.